# Why is my array being converted to an object when there's 22 or more elements? (node)

Tags: html, arrays, node.js, forms, express

I'm submitting a form with multiple checkboxes that share the same name. Receiving it with a node/express post route.

here is the html: https://pastebin.com/xeQae6GA

If I try to print out the length (`req.body.colors.length`) it will work if there's less than 22 elements in the array. If it's 22 or more, then it's equal to `undefined`. Printing out just `req.body.colors` confirms this.

Here are several outputs from several tries, adding more colors each time: https://pastebin.com/u6YSRmt6

This array is being stored in a database as an array, so it must be an array. Anyone know what's causing this, or how to deal with it?

---

Here is the full node code:

```
router.post('/product/:id', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log('COLORS --- count: '+req.body.colors.length);
  console.log(req.body.colors);

});
```

---

Complete form HTML: https://pastebin.com/0qTnTVFh

---

app.js body parser code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

most of my app.js (some unnecessary / sensitive code stripped out)
https://pastebin.com/1mTXiJkx

---

I have isolated my router and html to as simple as possible, here they are:

**test.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('TEST', {
    layout: false,
  })
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log('COLORS --- count: '+req.body.colors.length);
  console.log(req.body.colors);

  res.send(''+req.body.colors.length)
});

module.exports = router;
```

**test.hbs**

```
<form method="post" >

  <input id="radio-color-aqua" name="colors" value="aqua" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-aqua" style="background-color: #5191bd" title="aqua"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-army" name="colors" value="army" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-army" style="background-color: #836652" title="army"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-ash" name="colors" value="ash" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-ash" style="background-color: #ecebe9" title="ash"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-asphalt" name="colors" value="asphalt" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-asphalt" style="background-color: #505457" title="asphalt"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-athletic-heather" name="colors" value="athletic-heather" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-athletic-heather" style="background-color: #a8abb2" title="athletic-heather"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-baby-blue" name="colors" value="baby-blue" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-baby-blue" style="background-color: #b6c8db" title="baby-blue"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-berry" name="colors" value="berry" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-berry" style="background-color: #c13c7e" title="berry"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-black" name="colors" value="black" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-black" style="background-color: #27262b" title="black"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-black-heather" name="colors" value="black-heather" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-black-heather" style="background-color: #2A282B" title="black-heather"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-brown" name="colors" value="brown" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-brown" style="background-color: #372d2c" title="brown"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-dark-grey-heather" name="colors" value="dark-grey-heather" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-dark-grey-heather" style="background-color: #3E3C3D" title="dark-grey-heather"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-deep-heather" name="colors" value="deep-heather" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-deep-heather" style="background-color: #9B9A9F" title="deep-heather"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-forest" name="colors" value="forest" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-forest" style="background-color: #1F4A2E" title="forest"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-gold" name="colors" value="gold" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-gold" style="background-color: #f8a933" title="gold"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-heather-blue" name="colors" value="heather-blue" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-heather-blue" style="background-color: #86A9C9" title="heather-blue"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-heather-deep-teal" name="colors" value="heather-deep-teal" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-heather-deep-teal" style="background-color: #426275" title="heather-deep-teal"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-heather-forest" name="colors" value="heather-forest" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-heather-forest" style="background-color: #4F5549" title="heather-forest"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-heather-midnight-navy" name="colors" value="heather-midnight-navy" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-heather-midnight-navy" style="background-color: #35353F" title="heather-midnight-navy"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-heather-mint" name="colors" value="heather-mint" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-heather-mint" style="background-color: #72D3B4" title="heather-mint"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-heather-orange" name="colors" value="heather-orange" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-heather-orange" style="background-color: #D96E51" title="heather-orange"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-heather-raspberry" name="colors" value="heather-raspberry" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-heather-raspberry" style="background-color: #FC667D" title="heather-raspberry"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-heather-true-royal" name="colors" value="heather-true-royal" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-heather-true-royal" style="background-color: #5F98E6" title="heather-true-royal"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-kelly" name="colors" value="kelly" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-kelly" style="background-color: #016d56" title="kelly"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-leaf" name="colors" value="leaf" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-leaf" style="background-color: #548655" title="leaf"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-light-blue" name="colors" value="light-blue" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-light-blue" style="background-color: #94afca" title="light-blue"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-navy" name="colors" value="navy" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-navy" style="background-color: #37384a" title="navy"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-ocean-blue" name="colors" value="ocean-blue" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-ocean-blue" style="background-color: #619dc1" title="ocean-blue"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-olive" name="colors" value="olive" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-olive" style="background-color: #434c31" title="olive"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-pink" name="colors" value="pink" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-pink" style="background-color: #fcd1db" title="pink"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-red" name="colors" value="red" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-red" style="background-color: #a02331" title="red"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-silver" name="colors" value="silver" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-silver" style="background-color: #b8bcbf" title="silver"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-soft-cream" name="colors" value="soft-cream" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-soft-cream" style="background-color: #d3c4ad" title="soft-cream"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-steel-blue" name="colors" value="steel-blue" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-steel-blue" style="background-color: #4d657d" title="steel-blue"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-true-royal" name="colors" value="true-royal" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-true-royal" style="background-color: #18498c" title="true-royal"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-white" name="colors" value="white" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-white" style="background-color: #e2e3de" title="white"></label>

  <input id="radio-color-yellow" name="colors" value="yellow" type="checkbox"><label for="radio-color-yellow" style="background-color: #fbf271" title="yellow"></label>


  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This still seems to have the same error. Check off 18, 19, 20, 21 boxes, it will return that number. Check off 22 or more, and it will return undefined.

cut down the app.js: https://pastebin.com/wB2bivS0

Comment: Please, post your express code in here (not a link).

Comment: there isn't much more than what I mentioned, but I added it to my post

Comment: Just tried your code and it's always an array, even with all checked (36). So show how you are posting to `product/:id`

Comment: Included a paste of my form, cut it down from what it was but it still seems to have this issue at 22+ elements

Comment: Nothing, still the same. Provide more express code, how are you using body-parser etc. https://i.imgur.com/N2O3VEZ.png

Comment: I don't mind looking at your whole code, because there isn't anything wrong with the code you provided, I have no issues at all.

Comment: added my app.js file. Going to try to isolate the route / form a bit more.

Comment: OT: your html is not valid. Id attribute must not contain any white space characters. You should fix that.

Comment: @JoshuaK def a good idea to fix which I just did, didn't seem to change anything though: https://pastebin.com/ByU5gih8

Comment: Just to be sure, are you submitting the form directly, or you're sending it using AJAX?

Comment: Directly through a normal html form post

Comment: Finished isolating it (aside from the app.js), but still have the problem  . Added the codes to the post.

Comment: Cut down the app.js to only the essentials... still happening. Maybe it's something with my environment, I'm using cloud9 which is an instanced temp environment, haven't had any other weird issues like that though.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it, I'll get back to you.

Comment: That's good news. I tried adding [] to the end of each name attribute, which made it count the first 22, then add the rest as object values? Look at this insanity: https://pastebin.com/CEdGmyKF

Comment: I found your issue, I will write my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by `express-busboy`.

Checking the [code](https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy/blob/master/index.js#L152) of this package, it uses a querystring parser on `req.body`

```
 req.busboy.on('finish', () => {
    // This next line is the culprit
    req.body = qs.parse(qs.stringify(req.body));
    if (restrictMultiple) {
        [req.body, req.files].forEach(fixDups);
    }
    bbDone = true;
    finish();
});
```

In the [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) docs we can see the following:

> qs will also limit specifying indices in an array to a maximum index
>   of 20. Any array members with an index of greater than 20 will instead
>   be converted to an object with the index as the key
>   This limit can be overridden by passing an arrayLimit option

**Which is why everything works up until 20 items**

If you remove the busboy part, the code will work as expected:

```
// Remove this
bb.extend(app, {
    upload: true,
    path: './temp',
    allowedPath: /./
});
```

As I see it you have two options

**1)** Use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for file uploads instead of busboy

**2)** Fork `express-busboy` and add `{ arrayLimit: options.arrayLimit }`

**Note:** To avoid a possible DOS attack, you should set a reasonable limit :)

```
req.busboy.on('finish', () => {
    req.body = qs.parse(qs.stringify(req.body), { arrayLimit: options.arrayLimit });
    if (restrictMultiple) {
        [req.body, req.files].forEach(fixDups);
    }
    bbDone = true;
    finish();
});
```

And now call it like this:

```
 bb.extend(app, {
    upload: true,
    path: './temp',
    allowedPath: /./,
    arrayLimit: 50
 });
```

### UPDATE

My pull request has been merged and from `express-busboy >= 7.0.0`  you can pass an `arrayLimit` parameter.

---

Comment: Removing that section makes my post request timeout?

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative, and it doesn't make my post request timeout, weird.

Comment: The most beautiful console output I've ever seen: COLORS --- count: 26

Comment: I'm glad it worked out!, I added a PR to `express-busboy` https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy/pull/21

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it's greatly appreciated, would have driven me crazy for a long time (an even longer time). I ended forking my own, but yours would be a great addition to master.

Comment: @stackers my PR was merged and version 7.0.0 was release, you can update so you can drop your fork :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-busboy